# Git - How to handle change in index.d.ts

Tags: git, typescript-typings

I've cloned a project to add a feature I needed. 
The project is in typescript but is based on a js library.
So there is an in node_modules/@types/xyz/index.d.ts.

I had to modify this file in order to declare my two new methods.

But the index.d.ts does not show in git changes. So it won't be pushed to the repository and I guess my project will more than less broken.

So what's your advice about this index.d.ts?

Comment: Don't modify things in `node_modules`. You can augment a module in a separate file, or submit a PR for the npm module.

Comment: Changing 3rd party library index.d.ts in node_modules you'd make updating that library to a new version so much more complicated. Submitting PR to the author would be best approach if possible.